Kogito Compile error with property prefix start with small letter
I am using single-letter prefixes that are lowercase followed by an uppercase letter,
that is sRemittingBankName giving error.
If the perperty name start with small letter like sRemittingBankName then given error occured if I Use sremittingBankName then its work fine.
ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[error]: Build step org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.ProcessesAssetsProcessor#postGenerationProcessing threw an exception: org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompilerException: [org/kie/kogito/app/AOPIdentificationDetailsMessageMarshaller.java (41:14) : cannot find symbol
symbol:   method setSCountryOfResidence(java.lang.String)
